# prove the connectedness of a set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $Y\subset X$ are connected spaces and suppose that $A$ and $B$ are separation of $X-Y$. Prove that the union $Y\cup A$ is connected.

I want to prove by contradiction.Firstly I assume there exists a separation of $Y\cup A$,say $C\cup D$ .Then since $Y$ is connected,then $Y$ must belong to $C$ or $D$. Whithout loss of generality,we can suppose $Y\subset C$.I guess $C\cup B$ and $D\cup A$　should be the separation of $X$.But I don't know how to prove it in formal mathematics.

Comment: Since any discrete valued continuous function on $Y$ is constant, we can collapse $Y$ to a point $\{*\}$  and ask if the image of $A\cup Y$ is connected in $X/Y$.

Assume there is a non constant discrete valued continuous function $f$ on $[A] \cup \{*\}$, since $B$ or $[B] \cup \{*\}$ has to be open, we can extend this function to $X/Y$ via $f([B])=f(*)$, this is a contradiction to $X/Y$ being connected.